# Framework Reccomendation for a Mobile Looking App in Linux

Tags: desktop-client

Short question: Which framework should I use to design an app such that it looks like a mobile phone app, but works on Raspberry Pi?

I tried `python tkinter`, `qt`, `JavaFx` but all of them have very old-fashioned designs, like sites from 1990. I know react-native a bit, but I am not sure if that is suitable for this work. Are there any other frameworks for a beautiful design? I'd like to build something like Youtube Kids, but only with some colorful and good looking buttons, not videos.

Long story:

I have a Raspberry Pi with touch screen, and I want to install some very basic app which I'll be writing for kids where kids have only 2-3 options on the screen to select. The app will start in full screen mode, and the kids shouldn't access to the other resources in the desktop interface, and they should stay in the app (`xfce` is installed in Pi). I don't know if this is possible, but currently I created a non-sudo user, and the worst thing they can do is to plug a keyboard and access to terminal etc., but I think they can't make something break. So, I want to build some phone app, but to run on Raspberry Pi with touch screen. I still want to have fancy button click effects like many react-native libraries provide.

Thanks..

Comment: I'm wondering about your comment about Qt - you probably haven't looked far enough. Qt with QtQuick can produce some pretty good-looking GUI.

Comment: Thank you very much, I checked material design actually, but I got the feeling it would be a bit static in terms of button effects etc. QtQuick seems pretty nice, but I decided to go with flutter because there were Pi extensions for running flutter codes. I think it is also very rich in term of libraries. Do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: I'll add some other options in an answer, or it would become too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options that should work on Linux / Raspberry Pi. It also depends a little on which programming language you're most comfortable with.

As noted already, Qt with QtQuick can do some pretty nice things:
[image]

It is mostly designed to be used with C++.

[React](https://reactjs.org/), [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) or [Node](https://docs.nodegui.org/) are frameworks based on Javascript.

[Kivy](https://kivy.org/#gallery) is built on Python and may be sufficient for simple stuff.

Note that I have not tried any of these myself except Qt.